# CronJob, django and environment variables

Tags: django, openshift

I have built an application for django on Openshift v3 PRO with the django-ex template.  It works great.  I'm using POSTGRESQL with persistent storage.

I need a scheduled cron job to fire every hour to run some django management commands.  I'm using the CronJob pod for this.

My problem is this:  I need to create the CronJob job with the same environment variables that the django pod was created with (DATABASE_*, DJANGO_*, and others), but don't see an easy way to do this.

Any help would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to include a list of environment variables to set as part of the `containers` definition in the template spec for the job. I can't properly extract the resource definition for a `CronJob` using `oc explain` in OpenShift 3.6 because of the way it is registered, but I would expect the field to be similar to:

```
CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers.env

RESOURCE: env <[]Object>

DESCRIPTION:
     List of environment variables to set in the container. Cannot be updated.

    EnvVar represents an environment variable present in a Container.

FIELDS:
   name <string> -required-
     Name of the environment variable. Must be a C_IDENTIFIER.

   value    <string>
     Variable references $(VAR_NAME) are expanded using the previous defined
     environment variables in the container and any service environment
     variables. If a variable cannot be resolved, the reference in the input
     string will be unchanged. The $(VAR_NAME) syntax can be escaped with a
     double $$, ie: $$(VAR_NAME). Escaped references will never be expanded,
     regardless of whether the variable exists or not. Defaults to "".

   valueFrom    <Object>
     Source for the environment variable's value. Cannot be used if value is not
     empty.
```

Comment: Graham, thanks for the response.  So would you suggest I add it to the initial template that created the whole application (i.e. django-ex/openshift/django.json) or add it later?  I thought I had trouble with that in the past in the above spec wasn't allowed in the template.  Thanks again your help.

Comment: The original template doesn't include any jobs. Are you suggesting adding jobs to it? That doesn't help if your application is already deployed. If you are going to use the application image for the job, you are going to have to use certain tricks to have the job use it. Include your cronjob specification here so I can see it.

Comment: Yes, I am still in POC phase on how to get my django app moved from OS2 -> OS3, so adding it to the application template isn't an issue.  having trouble posting to comments my code, it's not too easy in SO.

Comment: Better to use list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openshift

Comment: Graham, will do, i'll move this over the Google Group forum.